How to create a Corrplot with Two Number Representation Methods?
Here is my code:
`library("corrplot")
set.seed(123)
mydata <- data.frame(
  A = runif(10, 0, 5),
  B = runif(10, 0, 5),
  C = runif(10, 0, 5),
  D = runif(10, 0, 5),
  E = runif(10, 0, 5)
)
result <- cor(mydata)

corrplot(result, 
         method = "circle", 
         type = "lower")
corrplot(result, 
         method = "number",
         type = "upper")`

What I need is to create a 5x5 table where circles are displayed in the upper half and numbers are displayed in the lower half. Is this possible?
Lower
Upper
I tried combining them as ggplots but that didnt work
